# mysql php getting variables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the content from mysql variables to use in php code, actually name (of the game), url (of the game) and alt (of the game). The image url and searching the database are working. I appreciate any help with coding. I don't know how to write the pointer to name, url and alt.

search_site.php

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="catchamouse3.png">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homestyles2.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="submit.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="allflashgames(3).css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="searchbar.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css">

<?php
include('func.php');

if(isset($_POST['keywords'])){
    $suffix = "";
    $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['keywords'])));
    $errors = array();
    if(search_results($keywords) === false){
        $errors[] ='<h1>We didn\'t find anything for &quot;'.$keywords.'&quot;</h1>';
    }
    if(empty($errors)){
        $results = search_results($keywords);
        $results_num = count($results);
        $suffix = ($results_num!=1)?'s':'';
        echo '<h1>',$results_num,' item',$suffix,' For &quot;',$keywords,'&quot;</h1>';
        foreach($results as $result){
            echo '

<span class="overimage">

<a href="$game_url" target="_blank">

<span class="hoverimage">
<span class="hovertext1line-home">',$result['name'],'</span><img class="onlinegameimage-home" src="',

$result['image_url'],'" alt=',$result['alt'],'>
</span>

</a>

</span>

';
        }
    }
    else{
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error,'<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

func.php

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db("my_search_test",$con);

    function search_results($keywords){
        $returned_results = array(); 
        $where ="";

        $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$keywords);
        $total_keywords = count($keywords);

        foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
            $where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
            if($key != ($total_keywords -1)){
                $where .=" AND ";
            }
        }
        $results = "SELECT name, image_url, game_url, alt FROM search_games WHERE $where";
        $results_num = ($results =mysql_query($results))? mysql_num_rows($results):0;
        if($results_num === 0){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            while($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
                $returned_results[] = array(
                    'image_url' => $results_row['image_url']

            );
        }
        return $returned_results;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're firing `search_results($keywords)` twice here. First while checking against `=== false` and second within the `if (empty($errors))` block. This is redundant. Make the call to `search_results($keywords)` one time, store the result, and use the result where needed.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Using `htmlspecialchars` will damage user data and should **not** be used when inserting into the database. Instead use that whenever you display values in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them to the `returned_results[]` array just like you did `image_url`

```
while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $returned_results[] = array(
        'name' => $results_row['name'],
        'image_url' => $results_row['image_url'],
        'game_url' => $results_row['game_url'],
        'alt' => $results_row['alt']
    );
}
```

**ADDED**

Per my comment, here's a cleaner, less redundant way to write your logic:

```
if (isset($_POST['keywords'])) {
    // ... code
    $results = search_results($keywords);
    if ($results === false) {
        echo '<h1>We didn\'t find anything for &quot;'.$keywords.'&quot;</h1>';
    }
    else {
        // we have results.. add rest of your code, ie. foreach(), etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("my_search_test",$con);

function search_results($keywords){
    $returned_results = array(); 
    $where ="";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$keywords);
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);

    foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
        $where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
        if($key != ($total_keywords -1)){
            $where .=" AND ";
        }
    }
    $results = "SELECT name, image_url, game_url, alt FROM search_games WHERE $where";
    $results_num = ($results =mysql_query($results))? mysql_num_rows($results):0;
    if($results_num === 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        while($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
            $returned_results[] = array(
                'image_url' => $results_row['image_url']

            );
        }
        return $returned_results;
    }
}
?>
```

You're firing search_results($keywords) twice here. First while checking against === false and second within the if (empty($errors)) block. This is redundant. Make the call to search_results($keywords) one time, store the result, and use the result where needed.

Comment: It looks like you copied the original post and the comment with the answer, but forgot to remove the extraneous noise.  Did you do anything other than copy and paste others' work?